# Increase speed for a ifelse-for loop in R, while filling matrix within loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, matrix

How can I increase the speed of the following loop operation, if the actual loop range is in 1000's?
In the code below:

DF3= Dataframe

OP and k are two columns in DF3 dataframe. Here, k takes a value from 1 to 10.

```
l1 <- seq(1, 10, 1)
E<-matrix(data=0, nrow=10, ncol=10)
for (i in seq_along(l1)){
  for (j in seq_along(l1)){
    E[i,j]=sum(ifelse (DF3$OP[DF3$k==i]<DF3$OP[DF3$k==j],1,0))
  }
}
```

DF3 example:

```
k   OP
1   60
1   30
1   38
1   46
2   29
2   35
2   13
2   82
3   100
3   72
3   63
3   45
```

Comment: Here are minor suggestions for better simplicity: (1) Instead `seq(1, 2552, 1)`, you can use `1:2552`; (2) Instead of `seq_along(l1)`, you can just use `l1`; (3), Instead of `sum(ifelse ( ... ,1,0))`, just drop the `ifelse()` function from it because summing logical TRUE/FALSE values is the same as summing 1's and 0's.

Comment: I think you'll scare away a lot of people trying to help by having a problem that's too big to show and/or just "play" with. While I know you want to expand this to much larger sizes, it might be helpful to show on a *much* smaller matrix, on the scale of 10x10 instead 2552x2552.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can simplify your nested `for` loops via using `combn`, which computes the values for upper triangular matrix only (but they are sufficient to obtain the values in the whole matrix)

```
E <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = max(DF3$k), ncol = max(DF3$k))
v <- split(DF3$OP, DF3$k)
E[lower.tri(E)] <- combn(v, 2, FUN = function(x) sum(do.call("-", x) < 0))
E[upper.tri(E)] <- max(lengths(v)) - t(E)[upper.tri(E)]
E <- t(E)
```

and finally you will get

```
> E
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    2    3
[2,]    2    0    3
[3,]    1    1    0
```

**Data**

```
> dput(DF3)
structure(list(k = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), OP = c(60L, 30L, 38L, 46L, 29L, 35L, 13L, 82L, 100L,
72L, 63L, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

The logical comparison

```
DF3$OP[DF3$k==i]<DF3$OP[DF3$k==j]
```

implies that across all groups of `k` that there are an equal number of results. If there were uneven amounts of records between groups, there would be issues with the calculation.

In your dataset, you have 4 records in each group. That suggests that instead of working with a dataframe, we may be better off working with a matrix.

```
ncols = length(unique(DF3$k))
mat = matrix(DF3$OP, ncol = ncols)
E = matrix(0L, ncols, ncols)

for (i in seq_len(ncols)) {
  x = mat[, i]
  for (j in seq_len(ncols)) {
    E[i, j] = sum(x < mat[, j])
  }
}
E

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    0    2    3
## [2,]    2    0    3
## [3,]    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need pairwise blocks of `DF3$OP` by `DF3$k` groups with reverse duplicates for greater and less than comparison, you are essentially filling in upper and lower triangle of a square matrix. Therefore, consider splitting data frame into OP blocks with `by` and pass into `combn` for matrix fill.

```r
OP_list <- by(DF3, DF3$k, function(sub) sub$OP)
OP_list
# DF3$k: 1
# [1] 60 30 38 46
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# DF3$k: 2
# [1] 29 35 13 82
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# DF3$k: 3

E <- matrix(data=0, nrow=max(DF3$k), ncol=max(DF3$k))

# COMPARE ACROSS ALL COMBINATIONS OF K-GROUP VECTORS
E[upper.tri(E)] <- combn(OP_list, 2, function(x) sum(x[[1]] < x[[2]]))
E[lower.tri(E)] <- combn(OP_list, 2, function(x) sum(x[[1]] > x[[2]]))

E
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    2    3
# [2,]    2    0    3
# [3,]    1    1    0
```

Should work for small or large sets. *See*: <kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/NROT25918)</kbd>